# Посоветуйте структуру реализации непрочитанных сообщений в чате android

Tags: android, android-service, chat, android-broadcastreceiver

Сразу извиняюсь за много букаф, не получается коротко описать проблему. Собственно есть список чатов который строится на лету из запроса на сервер, получаю ответ сервера и конструрирую объекты, затем их засовываю в recycleView и в фрагмент. Все уведомления о новых сообщениях идут черех FireBase. Собственно я сделал broadcastReciever в сервисе FireBase, и по приходу новых сообщений делаю широковещательный запрос и в фрагменте где получаю список чатов инкрементирую счетчик непрочитанных сообщений у определенного чата, который передается в широковещательном запросе. Когда я нахожусь в том фрагменте все нормально количество, непрочитанных сообщений отображается нормально. Но если нахожусь в другом фрагменте, и перехожу на исходный (запрос на сервер отправляется снова и снова строится список из объектов) счетчик теряется. Проблема как лучше сохранить этот счетчик и где, бд в приложении нет. Я уже домаю создать hashmap  массив и сохранять счетчик там "id_chat":"count_unread". И просто обнулять id_chat когда открываю этот чат. Но это дикий костыль, может быть есть идея более изящного способа. Я не прошу код просто, совет по структуре реализации.

Comment: В идеале само сообщение должно иметь свойство, хранящее состояние прочитанности. То есть это свойство должно жить не только локально в приложении, а приходить уже с сервера. При выводе списка пересчитывается количество помеченных, при открытии ("прочтении") локально помечается прочитанным, уменьшается счётчик и отправляется запрос на сервер о пометке прочитанным.

Comment: Если с серверной стороны такой поддержки нет и вы не можете на это повлиять, то сохраняйте счётчик в преференсы, инкремент ему делайте прямо в сервисе, в `onResume` фрагмента и в ресивере обновляйте вывод счётчика из префов. При прочтении уменьшайте запись в префах.

Comment: Да реализация на сервере думаю будет сложнее, и лишняя отправка данных нагрузка и высаживание аккума.. Да хорошая идея в префах сохранять, тоже думал об этом. Но есть момент, мне же их надо будет наверно в json паковать и сохранять, ведь это будет hashmap (ключ чата-значение), и их будет много. Пока что нет понимания как быстро это все паковать и  доставать от туда. Посыл понял, наверно так и сделаю.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем сделал счетчик через SharedPreferences все работает, когда приложение не свернуто, но когда свернуто, почему то в FirebaseMessagingService счетчик отказывается инкрементиться, если не трудно посоветуйте в комментарии как исправить.
Код функций в SharedPreferences:

```html
public static int getUnreadChatId(Context ctx, String chatID){

        SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("sec_pass", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int stored = pref.getInt(chatID, 0);
        return stored;
    }
    public static void createUnreadChatid(Context ctx, String chatID){

        SharedPreferences rootPass =  ctx.getSharedPreferences("sec_pass", 0);
        if(rootPass.contains(chatID)) return;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = rootPass.edit();
        editor.putInt(chatID, 0);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void CountSet(Context ctx, String chatID){

        SharedPreferences rootPass =  ctx.getSharedPreferences("sec_pass", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = rootPass.edit();
        int count = getUnreadChatId(ctx,chatID);
        count=count+1;
        editor.putInt(chatID, count);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void deleteUnreadChatID(Context ctx, String chatID){

        SharedPreferences rootPass =  ctx.getSharedPreferences("sec_pass", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = rootPass.edit();
        editor.remove(chatID);
        editor.commit();
    }
```